# ASP.Net MVC Razor DropDownListFor issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I am fairly new to coding, and am working on a personal MVC project. I am trying to implement a DropDown that uses values submitted by the user. I believe I have almost everything written correctly, but when I go to update an entity, I get the following error:

The ViewData item that has the key 'WrestlerId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Any assistance with this would be appreciated, and I will edit/update to help figure this out.

Edit: The error itself happens in the View on the following line of code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.WrestlerId, Model.Wrestlers, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Model**

```
public class TitleEdit
{
    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    public string TitleName { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Favorite")]
    public bool IsStarred { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Date Established")]
    public DateTime DateEstablished { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Current Champion")]
    public int? WrestlerId { get; set; }
    public string WrestlerName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Wrestlers { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Models.TitleCRUD.TitleEdit

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}



<h2>Updating Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TitleId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TitleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TitleName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TitleName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsStarred, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsStarred)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsStarred, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateEstablished, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateEstablished, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateEstablished, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WrestlerId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.WrestlerId, Model.Wrestlers, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Wrestlers, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div id="linkColor">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Controller**

```
//GET: Edit
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var service = CreateTitleService();
        var detail = service.GetTitleById(id);

        var wrestlerList = new WrestlerRepo();
        var model = new TitleEdit
        {
            TitleId = detail.TitleId,
            TitleName = detail.TitleName,
            IsStarred = detail.IsStarred,
            DateEstablished = detail.DateEstablished,
            WrestlerId = detail.WrestlerId
        };
        model.Wrestlers = wrestlerList.GetWrestlers();

        return View(model);
    }

    //POST: Edit
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, TitleEdit model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var wrestlerList = new WrestlerRepo();
            model.Wrestlers = wrestlerList.GetWrestlers();

            return View(model);
        }

        if (model.TitleId != id)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "ID Mismatch");
            return View(model);
        }

        var service = CreateTitleService();

        if (service.UpdateTitle(model))
        {
            TempData["SaveResult"] = "The title has been updated!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The title could not be updated.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

**GetWrestlers()**

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetWrestlers()
        {
            using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                List<SelectListItem> wrestlers = ctx.Wrestlers.AsNoTracking()
                    .OrderBy(n => n.RingName)
                    .Select(n =>
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = n.WrestlerId.ToString(),
                        Text = n.RingName
                    }).ToList();
                var wrestlerTip = new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = null,
                    Text = "Select a Wrestler"
                };
                wrestlers.Insert(0, wrestlerTip);
                return new SelectList(wrestlers, "Value", "Text");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: I have done breakpoints through the code, but I am not entirely sure where to look to find the value that isn't correct. As for the error itself, it happens in the view in the following line, which I'll update above:

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.WrestlerId, Model.Wrestlers, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: Can you change Model to model please? Common Mistake :) & I think that should work

Comment: This should work
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WrestlerId, Model.Wrestlers, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: Can you please check the values loaded in model.Wrestlers.@SMackeyCoding. Hope there will be null entries. Better to share that data also.

Comment: Umang I switched it to @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WrestlerId, Model.Wrestlers, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }), but I'm afraid it still threw the same error listed in the post.

Comment: @ScareCrow Do you mean the values when I set up the breakpoint? I see some null ones (string WrestlerName, & IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Wrestlers), but everything else has a value listed, or I could be reading it wrong. Or are you asking about the definition for Model.Wrestlers? That leads to the TitleEdit in the Model above.

Comment: Are you trying to bind the selected item id to "int? WrestlerId"? @SMackeyCoding